# where is my java home on my linux (centos 6) machine?

Tags: java, linux, maven, centos6

Maven build fails with this error:

No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

javac -version returns Eclipse Java Compiler 0.894_R34x.

which java returns /usr/bin/java. From there I did a readlink which returned the following
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java

I assigned this value to JAVA_HOME and tried to build the project using maven. Failed again. I also various versions of java under /usr/lib/jvm as shown here:

[image: jvms]

I tried various values from the above list and none of them seem to help.

Can someone help?

follow up:
The jdk folder contains only bin & lib folders. Is this correct?
[image]

Comment: "I assigned this value to JAVA_HOME" which value? `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java`? It needs to be the jdk's directory, not the java executable's location.

Comment: not the executable, i assigned /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64‌ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change `JAVA_HOME` to just `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64`

Comment: What Java compiler do you actually want to use?

Comment: This project I am trying to compile needs 1.7 which is what i want to use.

Comment: java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64 is 1.8 so no use. Do you actually want to use openjdk or oracles jdk?

Comment: at this point i am open to any suggestion, I dont have Oracle jdk installed. should I download and install it?

Answer (score 0):

Came across another thread that suggested to install this one: java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64

I did that and it is compiling now finally. Thanks everyone for your help.